# Safari on iMac (Mojave) can't resolve http://<hostname>.local

Tags: safari, dns, mojave

Safari 12.0 on my 2017 iMac cannot resolve local computer names. In my particular case the  computer is a RaspberryPi with a default web page.

If I put "pi-star.local" in the Safari address box, I receive "Safari can't open the page pi-star.local because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection". Safari loads the webpage if I put in the ip address instead.

[image]

pi-star.local works fine in Chrome and Firefox and webpage loads. I can also ping pi-star.local in terminal.

I have checked the Discovery App (for Bonjour from the Mac App Store) and can see pi-star.local listed.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I couldn't duplicate this issue on my 2015 MBP running Mojave. Have you tried clearing your data in Safari? Also, is the raspberry pi on WiFi or ethernet?

Comment: Cleared Safari history and caches. No change, pi-star.local still does not load. Raspberry Pi and iMac both on WiFi.